# Making list of months out of file data

Tags: python, list, loops

Hi I have data in this form
2016
January
31
44
0
44
0
39
2
39
1
44
1
51
0
45
0
48
0
48
0
51
0
45
1
48
1
55
1
48
0
48
2
53
1
50
1
54
1
46
1
52
1
51
1
55
1
46
1
50
0
54
0
55
1
57
1
55
1
50
1
46
1
46
0
February
29
45
1
50
1
48
1
48
1
53
1
48
0
50
0
57
0
62
0
55
1
55
1
57
1
51
1
55
0
57
1
55
1
57
1
52
1
51
1
52
1
51
1
51
1
60
0
57
1
61
1
60
1
57
1
52
1
53
1
March
31
55
1
54
1
57
1
57
1
63
1
60
1
52
1
53
1
55
1
55
1
55
1
51
1
53
1
48
1
51
0
53
0
57
0
63
0
61
0
55
1
55
1
57
1
53
1
54
1
57
0
59
1
51
1
55
1
64
0
68
0
73
0

all the data can change so I cant set define variables but it will be in that form of year at the top follow month then the day of the month and the data.

Im trying to figure out if I can split or something out to make a new list of just each month data? So like if the data has 10 months of data it would then make 10 list with that data in each month list. Thanks for the help

```
file = ("temperature.txt")
f = open(file,"r")
lines = f.read().split()
f.close()
```

I was trying to see if there is a way i can use like isalpha to check if it is a month name if so use that as a new list in copy that data into the list into it hits the next isalpha as that would be the next month?

Comment: Yes you can do whatever you want. [ask]

Comment: Please provide code you have written so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use **readlines()** instead of **read()**:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

The use **for** loop to get each month data. I don't know your real data, so just give you some code you can refer to:

```
month_name_list=["JAN", "FEB"]
for line in lines:
    if line.strip() in month_name:
        pass # Get month data in next lines
```